# How to read csv file with using pandas and cloud functions in GCP?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I just try to read csv file which was upload to GCS.

I want to read csv file which is upload to GCS with Cloud functions in GCP. And I want to deal with the csv data as "DataFrame".

But I can't read csv file by using pandas.

This is the code to read csv file on the GCS with using cloud functions.

```
def read_csvfile(data, context):
     try:
          bucket_name = "my_bucket_name"
          file_name = "my_csvfile_name.csv"
          project_name = "my_project_name"

          # create gcs client
          client = gcs.Client(project_name)
          bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
          # create blob
          blob = gcs.Blob(file_name, bucket)
          content = blob.download_as_string()
          train = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(content))
          print(train.head())
     
     except Exception as e:
          print("error:{}".format(e))
```

When I ran my Python code,  I got the following error.

`No columns to parse from file`

Some websites says that the error means I read un empty csv file. But actually I upload **non empty** csv file.
So how can I solve this problem?

please give me your help. Thanks.

----add at 2020/08/08-------

Thank you for giving me your help!
But finally I cloud not read csv file by using your code... I still have the error, `No columns to parse from file`.

So I tried new way to read csv file as Byte type. The new Python code to read csv file is bellow.

MAIN.PY

```
from google.cloud import storage
import pandas as pd
import io
import csv
from io import BytesIO 

def check_columns(data, context):
    try:
        object_name = data['name']
        bucket_name = data['bucket']

        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(object_name)
        data = blob.download_as_string()
        
        #read the upload csv file as Byte type.
        f = io.StringIO(str(data))
        df = pd.read_csv(f, encoding = "shift-jis")

        print("df:{}".format(df))     
        print("df.columns:{}".format(df.columns)) 
        print("The number of columns:{}".format(len(df.columns)))
```

REQUIREMENTS.TXT

```
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
Pillow==5.4.1
qrcode==6.1
six==1.12.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
google-cloud-storage==1.30.0
gcsfs==0.6.2
pandas==1.1.0
```

The output I got is bellow.

```
df:Empty DataFrame
Columns: [b'Apple, Lemon, Orange, Grape]
Index: []
df.columns:Index(['b'Apple', 'Lemon', 'Orange', 'Grape'])
The number of columns:4
```

So I could read only first record in csv file as df.column!? But I could not get the other records in csv file...And the first column is not the column but normal record.

So how can I get **some** records in csv file as **DataFrame** with using pandas?

Could you help me again? Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Pandas, since version 0.24.1, can directly read a Google Cloud Storage URI.

For example:

`gs://awesomefakebucket/my.csv`

Your service account attached to your function must have access to read the CSV file.

Please, feel free to test and modify this code.

*I used Python 3.7*

**function.py**

```py
from google.cloud import storage
import pandas as pd

def hello_world(request):
    # it is mandatory initialize the storage client
    client = storage.Client()
    #please change the file's URI
    temp = pd.read_csv('gs://awesomefakebucket/my.csv', encoding='utf-8')
    print (temp.head())
    return f'check the results in the logs'
```

**requirements.txt**

```
google-cloud-storage==1.30.0
gcsfs==0.6.2
pandas==1.1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I used the code you supplied here. But  I still have the same error like "No columns to parse from file"... Why...
I tried new way to read csv file. The new Python code is followed.
I want to show my new code, but I could not write it here because I have a limitation of number of letter. So please check the just bellow first post.

Comment: @alan How are you uploading your CSV file? How was it created? in your local environment is it working fine? I tested with a csv created on MS EXCEL and with [this](https://support.spatialkey.com/spatialkey-sample-csv-data/) internet sample, both works fine, also I uploaded both files by using the web ui, are you uploading your csv as binary file?

Comment: Finally I could read csv file which was upload to GCS. The problem is that I add many kind of library in REQUIREMENTS.TXT. So when I cleared it all, then add only code you gave me, Finally I could read csv finally. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @alan If my answer was helpful, please mark as valid and upvote it